# Why won't this CSS triangle play nicely with a fixed background image?

Tags: css, background, fixed

Example: http://cdpn.io/EaDdx

Next to the "Sample Title" you can see the arrowhead I'm trying to create. I'm trying to get this to work in the same manner as the rectangles and the circle, allowing it to act as a 'porthole' to it's own fixed background image.

I've tried everything from using borders to create a triangle (which blocked out the body's background image), to using various rotations, alternations of use between an actual background image and background gradient.

Right now I'm using basically using [this](http://forrst.com/posts/CSS3_Triangle_Gradients-XGU) method, ***as so***:

```
.gradient-triangle {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: -25px;
        clip: rect(auto 25px 50px auto);
}

.gradient-triangle:after  {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        left: 9px;
        right: 0px;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(49%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #000000 0%,#000000 49%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

This is mainly a chrome issue right now, though as you'll see, it does something different in each browser, which is pretty odd.

I haven't seen any other websites that do this sort of thing, using fixed background images, within elements, to offer the "porthole" style view. I'd be interested to see any that anyone may know of, to checkout how they handle things similar to this.

**Edit:** Just to clarify what I think is causing this. Usually a fixed background image is relative to the window, not the element it's assigned to. As soon as that element is rotated, the background image becomes relative to it. There's a good chance this is a browser bug, I'd just like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I could get the following to work in Chrome:

CSS

```
.filler {
    height: 2000px;
}

.test2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 370px;
    left: 219px;
    top: 10px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: -266px;
    background-position-y: -107px;
}
.container {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: -275px;
     margin-top: -116px;
     clip: rect(-265px, 693px, 0px, 428px);
}
.container2 {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
     position: absolute;
}

.test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 400px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 85px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.test, .test2 {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/900/600);
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4n5V/show)

There is alot of hand-set positions; probably that could be set easier playing with transform-origins.

Also, I have a difference between positions in Chrome (on one side) and Firefox - IE (on the other). Still trying to understand why ..

Comment: Just had a quick glance at this but it does look to be what I'm after. Shall check it out in more detail later. I've scanned over your code and it's pretty much in line with different methods I've previously tried, I guess there's something I've missed somewhere. Kudos anyway! Shall let you know how I get on with this. :)